# Issues styling the default Twitter Widget

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, twitter

I'm working on a WP site and am having lots of trouble styling twitter’s default widget. More on this widget can be found here: https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines

The main issue is that my CSS styles are being overwritten no matter how deep I stack elements or use "!important” when working with this widget. For example, I am using the below code to try and change the outer widget's border-radius from 5px to 0px but NOTHING changes.

```css
.timeline {
   border-radius:0 !important;
   -webkit-border-radius:0 !important;
   -moz-border-radius:0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script>
    !function(d,s,id){
        var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
        if(!d.getElementById(id)){
            js=d.createElement(s);
            js.id=id;
            js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
        }
    }
    (document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>

<a
   class="twitter-timeline"
   href="https://twitter.com/TadHeigel"
   data-widget-id="588706214483210242">
</a>
```

The CSS posted above effectively changes the styling of the widget when I am using my browser’s editor... but NOT when pasted into my actual CSS file (which is set to load last, after all other CSS).

This leads me to believe that the CSS file the above twitter script is pulling from is what is over-riding my CSS.

Does anyone know how to actually style this widget? Or maybe more importantly, does anyone know how to load the "default" twitter widget CSS file so I can then edit it directly? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

**Page with widget script:** 
http://eldeco.mainstreetwebworx.com/

Comment: The class in your HTML is `twitter-timeline` but in your CSS it's just `timeline`. Aside from that, the Twitter & Facebook widgets are just horrendous and incredibly difficult to style. I'm currently in the process of writing my own to allow me full control over the styling of every single element within them.

Comment: The .timeline element is part of the structure that the twitter widget automagically creates. ;)  This .timeline element has the defined border-radius I am trying to change. The inspect element tool shows this, but I cannot post a screenshot due to not enough stack-overflow "points".    Do you know of any way to force the script to load a separate CSS file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED IT!**

So basically you need to tell Twitter to pull from your CSS file after it loads all other styles, and then you have complete control over your Twitter Widget. Although I have found lots of confusion surrounding this topic, there is actually a very simple way to tweak all the Twitter Elements.

Here is the detailed process from start to finish.

**FIRST:** Download this JS File and upload it to your file structure appropriately. I'd place it in your JS folder. If you don't have a JS folder, you can create one.

*Just make sure to correctly change your directory path.* You can grab the file from Github here:

https://github.com/kevinburke/customize-twitter-1.1/blob/master/customize-twitter-1.1.min.js

**SECOND:** Load this file. I would recommend placing the code in your header with other scripts. Here is an example:

```html
<script src="/wp-content/themes/reverie/js/customize-twitter-1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

*Remember to correctly change your directory path!*

**THIRD:** Create your Twitter Widget. Just login to Twitter and then access this link:

https://twitter.com/settings/widgets

**FOURTH:** Paste your newly created code into your webpage... like so:

```html
<a
    class="twitter-timeline"
    href="https://twitter.com/TadHeigel"
    data-widget-id="588706214483210242">
</a>

<script>
    !function(d,s,id){
    var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
      if(!d.getElementById(id)){
        js=d.createElement(s);
        js.id=id;
        js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
      }
    }
    (document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

**FIFTH:** Place the following code below your twitter widget script.

*Remember to correctly change your directory path.*

```html
<script>
    var options = {
        "url": "/wp-content/themes/reverie/css/app.css"
    };
    CustomizeTwitterWidget(options);
</script>
```

**SIXTH AND FINAL:** Play around! Just target the widget's elements using an "inspect element" tool and then paste the new tweaked CSS into your specified stylesheet.

**Hope this helps solve lots of the confusion out there on how to tweak these Twitter Widgets. Enjoy.**

Answer (score 0):

There's alot of information [here](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines#customization) regarding customization (which I'm sure you've gone through and actully won't let you override the 'border-radius' property). Or you could use this handy little snippet to pull in your feed which allows for full customization (I'm in no way affiliated but I have used it before)

[Twitter-Post-Fetcher](https://github.com/jasonmayes/Twitter-Post-Fetcher)